# Can't trigger mouseover on an element within an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, mouseevent, mouseover

Within my main page(A), there's an iframe, which loads another page(B) that has a simple element, and within the code for page(B), there is some jQuery that binds a mouseover event handler on the simple element.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to fire the mouseover event within page(A). However, it doesn't seem to want to respond to the trigger (I did reach into the iframe's document and currectly got the element, but when I try to do that element .mouseover(), it just seems to be ignored).

I've confirmed that the event handler is correctly attached to the element, because when I move my mouse over the element within that iframe, the event handler does get triggered.

HOWEVER, the interesting thing that I found out is, if I manually attach another event handler on that simple element within the iframe (via Chrome's console window), and then try to fire it on page(A), that event handler I manually added via console does get fired.

Can someone tell me what I'm overlooking?

Comment: is your iframe on the same domain ?

Comment: Yes it is, which is why I was able to manually attach an event handler from console.